# The derivative of the cross product of two vectors with respect to one of the vectors

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Suppose we want to take the partial derivative of $(\vec{B} \times \vec{A})^2$ with respect to $\vec{A}$.

We write $(\vec{B} \times \vec{A})^2 = (\vec{B} \times \vec{A}) \cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{A}) $

1/ How we define $\frac {\partial}{\partial {\vec{A}}}$?

Suppose $\vec{A}=A_x(t)\vec{i}+A_y(t)\vec{j}+A_z(t)\vec{k}$.

Should we define  $\frac {\partial}{\partial {\vec{A}}}$ first for ?

$\frac {\partial}{\partial {A_{x}}}, \frac {\partial}{\partial {A_{y}}}, \frac {\partial}{\partial {A_{z}}}$

And then somehow obtain $\frac {\partial}{\partial {\vec{A}}}(\vec{B} \times \vec{A}) \cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{A})$?

2/ Can we show that  $\frac{{\partial (\vec{B} \times \vec{A})^2}}{\partial \vec{A}}=2 \vec{B} \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})$

Comment: Another approach is to replace $\vec{A}\to \vec{A}'=\vec{A}+\epsilon \vec{h}$ and expand $(\vec{B}\times \vec{A})^2$ to first order in $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the vector $$c=(b\times a)$$
Then calculate the differential and gradient of the function using standard vector algebra.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= c\cdot c \\
d\phi &= dc\cdot c \;+\; c\cdot dc \\
 &= 2c\cdot dc \\
 &= 2c\cdot(b\times da) \\
 &= 2(c\times b)\cdot da \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial a}
 &= 2(c\times b) \\
 &= 2(b\times a)\times b \\
 &= 2b\times(a\times b) \\
}$$
The nice thing about the differential approach is that the differential of a vector has the same dimensions as the underlying vector and obeys all of the rules of vector algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Writing vectors $A$ and $B$ as column vectors, it is well-known that

$ A \times B = S B $

where $S = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - A_z && A_y \\ A_z && 0 && - A_x \\ -A_y && A_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Then

$(B \times A) \cdot (B \times A) = (A \times B) \cdot (A \times B) = (S B)^T (SB) = B^T S^T S B = - B^T S^2 B $

where the last equality comes from the fact that $S$ is skew-symmetric.

Now taking the gradient of the dot product of the cross products is trivial, and is given by

$ \nabla \bigg( (A \times B) \cdot (A \times B) \bigg) = - 2 S^2 B $